# Ice for mikva now that mikvaot are closed

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, maseches-mikvaos

Since now there is a difficulty with mikvaot. Can one make ice in a freezer put it into an empty mikva and then warm it up. Would that be kosher. 
https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/creating-a-mikveh-with-snow-natural-and-artificial-ice-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter
This is now being done in many private garden mikvaot.

Comment: You already cite an article that says it's a machloket and lists many modern opinions. Now you ask here. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I will be honest I only saw the article after I asked the question. I didnt want to delete the question since others had seen it so I decided to add it in. Anyway it is very timely. Many people are making 'iced' mikvaot not knowing that it is a machloket. Maybe not members of this site but they are being sold in thousands at about 200 for chazon ish size.